# Default Condition In Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions

Our store is planning to support shipping in multiple countries.

Previously the promotional rules did not have any shipping country attribute as part of the conditions as it was not required. Now we need to differentiate between rules which are applicable in all countries vs rules which are applicable only in specific countries.

The magento way for this is that we select shipping country for rules where we need to restrict the applicability to certain countries and skip the condition if it needs to be applicable to all the countries.

Now we want to include a default condition for shipping country with default value as India while creating new rules so as to make it clear for the user creating rules.

How is it possible and where the changes have to be made for including shipping country as default attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules** and create a new rule.

Select conditions and select the shipping country.

[image]

Comment: This is already known to us. Sorry that the question was ambiguous(I have now modified the question to include this)
What we want is to include a default condition on rule creation which would be rendered on the form when the user wants to create a new rule.